# Does Flash in the Wii support h264?

Tags: flash, h.264, flashlite, wii

I'm working on a streaming video player that can play either FLV or H264.  I have it working on the PC and my attempts to get the Wii to play H264 have come up short.

With the recent browser update the Wii has Flash Lite 3.1 (upgraded from Flash 7) which has support for H264 ([Adobe Flash Lite version comparison.](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashlite/version/))  I've tried different bitrates and even no audio.  Has anyone else gone through this already?

By the way the Wii now has the browser for free (at least here in the US).

Comment: I don't see why this doesn't fit the criteria for a programming question. It's detailed and specific, written clearly and simply, and probably of interest to other programmers. It also doesn't fit any of the criteria for a question one shouldn't ask here.

Comment: Put another way - how is this any different from asking whether a certain Java implementation supports a particular class? It's a programming question about a platform.